# How to Configure a vm on the same machine to do remote desktop

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

I want to achieve following:
(Note I'd like to get this done first of all with Win7 as both host and vm OS)

1. Install Windows 7/xp/Windows 8 VM on Windows 7/Windows 8 host machine
2. Configure it so that I can connect to it via remote desktop.

This is because I use a screen reader software and audio output directly from VMs is not highly responsive. My software has a feature that it can connect to its copy on the remote machine (during rdp session) and then start receiving the text description which it translates into audio on the client (host in this case) machine.

I want to know:

1. Which VM software can let me do this – VMWare/Ms Virtual PC or VirtualBox
2. If it is possible with every VM software, could you give an example of how to do this with anyone of these 3? Specifically, I know how to install Windows on VM (on both VMWare/Virtual PC), but don't really know how to configure a network such that I can remote into that VM from host OS.

Hope it clarifies what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Edited my question to be more specific. Actually I don't have idea as to how to configure VM OS network such it it can be reachable from host OS using remote desktop (MSTSC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guest system to be accessible from the host system. To do this, you'll need to configure the VM's network adapter to be connected in bridged mode.

This is possible in VirtualBox & VMWare

- To do this in VirtualBox, from the VM settings, select Network section and select Attached to as "Bridged Adapter"
  [image]
- To do this in VMWare, right click your VM, choose VM settings and under network connection, select "Bridged"

[image]

I haven't worked with VirtualPC, so I have no idea if this is possible