# Unable to pass stored credentials to vmconnect

Tags: windows, powershell, hyper-v, credentials, credentials-manager

I've followed numerous threads shown below regarding using stored credentials and I'm still unable to pass them to the **vmconnect** command.  When I store a credential then use **vmconnect** like:

```
vmconnect mypc ubuntu-pc /credential (Get-StoredCredential -UserName bernie)
```

I receive this message regardless of the method used:

> "The credential 'System.Management.Automation.PSCredential' is not in the credential store"

I also tried manually adding credentials using the Windows 10 credential manager.

How can I use a stored credential with the **vmconnect** command?

Methods Tried:

- https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-get-credential/
- https://purple.telstra.com.au/blog/using-saved-credentials-securely-in-powershell-scripts
- https://practical365.com/blog/saving-credentials-for-office-365-powershell-scripts-and-scheduled-tasks/

Answer (score 0):

Try using cmdkey instead. Store the user/pass like this:

If on domain

`cmdkey /generic:domain\server /user:domain\bernie /pass:1234`

and if not on a domain:

`cmdkey /generic:.\server /user:.\bernie /pass:1234` (can also replace dot with local machinename)

After this has been added run `cmdkey /list` and look at the bottom entry for value Target=.

Next, connect with vmconnect like:

`VmConnect.exe "mypc" "ubuntu-pc" /credential LegacyGeneric:target=.\bernie`

The last target= parameter will be whatever the value returns when you run cmdkey /list

Comment: I tried what you suggested and get this error when running vmconnect.  I've tried numerous permutations of the cmdkey to no avail.

"The credential 'LegacyGeneric:target=bernie' is not in the credential store"

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the regular Remote Desktop Connection to connect to the VM.

It might require some fiddling based on how you've set up your VM and the network between the host. I don't exactly remember which one helped me (been at it for days) but some of these definitely helped:

- [How to Configure a vm on the same machine to do remote desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/471578/how-to-configure-a-vm-on-the-same-machine-to-do-remote-desktop)
- [RDP into VirtualBox on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/609065/rdp-into-virtualbox-on-windows)
- [Remote Desktop Connection with VM not working](https://superuser.com/questions/504578/remote-desktop-connection-with-vm-not-working)
- [Unable to RDP onto a VM hosted on another LAN computer](https://superuser.com/questions/995919/unable-to-rdp-onto-a-vm-hosted-on-another-lan-computer)